# Yii2: How to join tables with Query Builder?

Tags: join, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, query-builder

I'm using the Yii2 framework for a very basic stock software. I have two tables of a very basic stock software:

```
products = (id_product, name)
movements = (id_movement, quantity, date)
```

The **products table** has all the product of a supermarket.
When the supermarket buy a product, it is registered in the **movements table**.

I want to show a grid with the current stock in the **index.php view**.  I am thinking to have a **actionIndex function** to get the total of each products.

Basically I want to do this:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    Get movements and products from database;
    For each product {
        if (movement is IN) {
            add();
        }
        else {
            subtract();
        }
    }
    return...
}
```

Using Gii Code Generator, I made a CRUD for **products** and a CRUD for **movements**.

So first, **I need to get the products and movements from database**. Without Yii, I can make a simple JOIN query. But I have no idea how to do it using Yii. What is the best way to do it? I would like to use the query builder.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447538/how-to-use-join-in-yii2-active-record-for-relational-model) but I didn't work for me. And this [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html) but I really don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `innerJoin`   or similar function

```
    $result=    (new Query())
        ->select('table1.col1, table1.col2,,,, table2.co1, table2.col2 ...')
        ->from('products ')
        ->innerJoin('movements', 'product.key= movements.key');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html